# Fl_Window subclass doesn't work

Tags: c++, user-interface, fltk

As titled above, i'm trying to get an extremely simple FLTK 1.3.3 application working. 
But, even with only a simple Fl_Window and 1 Fl_Button, nothing seems to work. Can anyone help?

```
class MainEditorWindow : public Fl_Window
{
public:
    MainEditorWindow(int _width, int _height, std::string _title);
    ~MainEditorWindow();

    virtual void draw();
    virtual int handle(int _event);
private:
    Fl_Button* m_btnExit;
};
```

And here is the Implementation

```
MainEditorWindow::~MainEditorWindow()
{

}

int MainEditorWindow::handle(int _event)
{
    return 1;
}

void MainEditorWindow::draw()
{
    m_btnExit->redraw();
}

MainEditorWindow::MainEditorWindow(int _width, int _height, std::string _title) : Fl_Window(_width, _height, _title.c_str())
{
    this->begin();
    m_btnExit = new Fl_Button(0, 0, 40, 40, "EXIT");
    m_btnExit->color(FL_RED);
    this->color(FL_WHITE);
    this->end();
}
```

But when simply running the application like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MainEditorWindow* mw = new MainEditorWindow(800, 600, "SHIP Editor");
    mw->show(argc,argv);
    return Fl::run();
}
```

The window shows up fine, its resizable movable etc,  the `draw()` - function is being called and all that. But the window itself is just *blank.* It simply shows nothing, especially not the `Fl_Button`. Can anybody tell me why this occurs? As far as i can tell, there should be nothing particularily wrong with my code.

Comment: Don't you need to add the button to the window in some way?

Comment: @Hedanito creating widgets between `begin()` and `and()` does exactly that.

Comment: I can only imagine the threading hazards :|

Comment: @Hedanito i feared that aswell - since FLTKs API is antiquated to say the least. They have a `add(Fl_Widget*)` function though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call Fl_Window::draw()

```
    void MainEditorWindow::draw()
    {
      m_btnExit->redraw();
      Fl_Window::draw();
    }
```

And maybe you want the button is clickable too

```
    int MainEditorWindow::handle(int _event)
    {
      //return 1;
      return(Fl_Window::handle(_event));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `MainEditorWindow` constructor:

```
MainEditorWindow(int _width, int _height, const std::string& _title) 
        : Fl_Window(_width, _height, _title.c_str()) {
    // begin grouped GUI object creation
    Fl_Group::begin();
    // alter x,y coords of button as necessary
    m_btnExit = new Fl_Button(0,0,40,40,"EXIT");
    m_btnExit->color(FL_RED);
    // end grouped GUI object creation
    Fl_Group::end();
    // defines resizable widget for group
    Fl_Group::resizable(this);
    this->color(FL_WHITE);
    // display window
    Fl_Window::show();
}
```

Then in main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MainEditorWindow mw(800, 600, "SHIP Editor");
    return Fl::run();
}
```

Here we have added the button to a group and then invoked `Fl_Window::show()` inside the constructor to display it.

Note there is no need to make `mw` a pointer to `MainEditorWindow` in `main`.

Comment: @calcyss Try altering the (x,y) co-ords of the button (first 2 args of `Fl_Button` constructor)

Comment: The problem seems to be with the subclassing of `Fl_Window`. I tried simply creating a `Fl_Window` and add a button to it, that worked.

Comment: Can you try creating a subclass of `Fl_Window`?

Comment: I have an fltk application I made a while ago which uses a similar code structure to my above answer and this works, but I can try another test case in a while.

Comment: hm... calling the base class `draw()` method with `Fl_Window::draw();` did the trick, it works now. Weird.